# How can I trigger method in Controller in ASP.NET with hangfire?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, triggers, hangfire

I want to run a method in the controller every day. I did everything step by step for Hangfire, but it still doesn't work. This is my code in the controller, does anyone have an idea why this is not done automatically every day?

Thank you

```cs
public void  TriggerFunction()
{ 
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Update(), Cron.Daily());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hit `TriggerFunction` action first to add your daily `Update()` job, then `Update()` will be called automatically every day, otherwise hangfire will not create the job. I think a better way is to add the daily job somewhere else and triggered on
some user behaviour like save, and the daily job will trigger the action/mother in the controller.