# How to trigger method in the background in Controller ASP.NET MVC with c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, triggers, controller

I want to trigger a method in the background in my controller every day. But I would like to do this in C # without external triggers. Can someone help me? Or does someone have an example for me what that looks like?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)?

Comment: yes also Hangfire but it doesn't work...

Comment: Could you update the question and add the code you wrote when you used Quartz?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297165/how-can-i-trigger-method-in-controller-in-asp-net-with-hangfire

Answer (score 0):

You need a worker service in your ASP.Net Application. It's in the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Check the Timed background tasks section. Set the timer to 86.400sec

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `job scheduling system` like [**Quartz**](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [**Hangfire**](https://www.hangfire.io/)

If you need a `dashboard` to manage your jobs, **Hangfire** is a better option, if you just want to trigger a simple job **Qartz** is a better option.

If you need sample code. [Quartz Sample project with ASP.NET Core controller](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hanging fire.
An easy way to perform background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. No Windows service or separate process is required.

Here is a detailed instruction:
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/highlight.html